# How to change database values on theme update

Tags: theme-development, database, hooks, migration, updates

I have a theme released into the wild but have not prefixed the post type appropriately. Yes, I know, it's a shame and I regret it :(

So, I am currently using `acme` as the post type name, but I' like to change it to `prefix_acme`.

I'm looking for the most appropriate function/hook to rename the post type without losing any data so users will not experience a difference.

Can the database values under `wp_posts -> post_type` simply be changed during a theme update?

If so, then can the same be done for `wp_postmeta -> meta_key` without losing the `meta_value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be the full answer but i think it will greatly help you if you are able to make templates - you will be able to do this:

In theme init (when it installs) make function which will make db query to find all post with your post_type and renames post_type to your new value. (i think this is very easy and can be done with 1 query).

Then make sure your new theme supports that new post_type (just change post_type name) - THAT's IT! CLients won't loose anything and you'll fix it in seconds :)

MAybe this query will do it: (not tested)

```
function fixme($oldname, $new_typename){
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE ".$wpdb->posts." SET post_type = %s WHERE post_type = %s", $new_typename, $oldname ) );                                                                                                                                                        

}
```

You can use in function this: `$wpdb->prefix` if you need to get prefix.

OR you can use `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'your_function_name' );` so after theme will be installed it will call your defined function, but then you have to change it to not use parameters to set new post_type but write them manually (assign to $oldname, $new_typename values)

And YES you can do the same on meta keys too (if they are not sanitized, if they are -then you'll need php more than in regular situation)..you can do whatever you want with queries, cause they are direct to database.

Comment: Hey Tom, yes this is really helpful! I will try your suggestions and report back.

Comment: Worked like a charm! :)

Here's my code, I am actually looping through a specified array of post types and adding a prefix: https://gist.github.com/2653299

Comment: Glad that this helped :) Also if you select my answer as correct one - people would know that this helps solve the problem you had with no need to read all comments :) And of course this will also adds for me some points which is like reputation, and having good rep is nice :D

Comment: Of course :) Done.

Comment: Also updated the gist to be more robust, checking first to see if the new post type already exists :)